# ActiveMQ bad certificate when introduce SSL

Tags: ssl, activemq-classic

I am trying to use openwire+ssl in my ActiveMq. I am using the docker images provided by rmohr/activemq.

What I ran the following commands to generated necessary files since the broker_localhost.cert has expired.

```
keytool -genkey -alias broker -keyalg RSA -keystore broker.ks
keytool -export -alias broker -keystore broker.ks -file broker_cert
keytool -genkey -alias client -keyalg RSA -keystore client.ks
keytool -import -alias broker -keystore client.ts -file broker_cert
keytool -export -alias client -keystore client.ks -file client_cert
keytool -import -alias client -keystore broker.ts -file client_cert
```

Then in the `activemq.xml` I added:

```xml
<sslContext keyStore="file:${activemq.base}/certs/ActiveMq/broker.ks"
      keyStorePassword="password" trustStore="file:${activemq.base}/certs/ActiveMq/broker.ts"
      trustStorePassword="password"/>
```

as well as:

```xml
<transportConnector name="openwire+ssl" uri="ssl://0.0.0.0:61617?transport.enabledProtocols=TLSv1"/>
```

When I run `docker compose` to create the ActiveMQ instance I added an environment variable as:

```
environment:
      - ACTIVEMQ_SSL_OPTS="-Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore=/opt/activemq/certs/ActiveMq/broker.ks -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword=password -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=/opt/activemq/certs/ActiveMq/broker.ts -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=password -Djavax.net.debug=ssl,handshake"
```

After that I import the broker_cert generated in the previous steps in Windows `Manage user certificates` as `Trusted Root Certification Authorities`.

Then I build my Asp.Net Core project to access the ActiveMQ broker

```
var uri = new Uri(@"ssl://localhost:61617?trace=true&needClientAuth=true&transport.serverName='MoveQ Broker'");
ITransportFactory sslTransportFactory = new SslTransportFactory();
((SslTransportFactory)sslTransportFactory).SslProtocol = "Tls";
ITransport transport = sslTransportFactory.CreateTransport(uri);
_connection = new Connection(uri, transport, new IdGenerator());
((Connection)_connection).UserName = "username";
((Connection)_connection).Password = "password";
_session = _connection.CreateSession(AcknowledgementMode.AutoAcknowledge);
```

However I keep getting

```
activemq | WARN | Transport Connection to: tcp://172.17.0.1:35356 failed: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: bad_certificate
```

Can anyone help to see what step(s) I may miss?

Comment: Do you really need 2-way SSL or would 1-way SSL suffice?

Comment: I think one way should be sufficient, just like how https works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just need 1-way SSL and you're using self-signed certificates then you don't need a truststore on the broker or a keystore on the client. You just need a keystore on the broker and a truststore on the client. Generate these resources like so:

```
keytool -genkey -keystore broker-keystore.ks
keytool -export -keystore broker-keystore.ks -file broker.cer
keytool -import -keystore client-truststore.ks -file broker.cer
```

Then use `broker-keystore.ks` on the broker and `client-truststore.ks` on the client.

Comment: Hi Justin, thank you for giving advice. I am not exactly sure how to apply client-truststore.ks on the client.  I am currently having a docker image running ActiveMQ server and then use an application in the host machine to publish message to the ActiveMQ server. Thank you

Comment: BTW, my application is written in C#, rather than JAVA

Comment: Just realise in c#, we can specify ClientCertFilename and ClientCertPassword, shall I spencify client-truststore.ks and its password here?

Comment: I'm not familiar with SSL configuration for C# clients so you'll need to refer to your client's documentation for that part. That said, the JKS format that `keytool` uses by default was made for Java applications so you'll probably need to convert it to another format in order to use it with your C# client. Again, you'd need to consult the client docs to know what formats it supports.

Comment: Thank you Justin. Eventually I make it working with C# application by using NMSConnectionFactory. There is no more error when connecting my C# application to ActiveMQ. Thanks a lot