# ActiveMQ WSS gives ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID

Tags: ssl, activemq-classic

I basically follow the steps in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59475322/activemq-bad-certificate-when-introduce-ssl) to create SSL certificates for ActiveMQ. Now with some help, I can connect my C# application to ActiveMQ. However when I tried to connect my Angular application to it, I got ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID error.

I actually have an ActiveMQ instance running in AmazonMQ and it works fine with my Angular application. So I think this is the issue of the certificate when I try to run the ActiveMQ in my own docker image.

For some details, I am using a domain name dev.com pointing to 127.0.0.1, which is set in host file. I am using dev.com to access both C# application and Angular application so I plan to use wss://dev.com:61619 to access ActiveMQ from my Angular application. When I generate keystore, I specify dev.com as the CN. In addition, I have another self-signed certificate generated with OpenSSL for Angular and C# application, not sure if there will be any conflict between them.

Can anyone please help to see what could be wrong?

Thank you

Comment: do you get that error in chrome ? and is it self signed

Comment: Note that setting CN is not sufficient with browsers like Chrome. You have to set Subject Alternative Names too.

Comment: Hi Dilek, yes, I generate the certificate from the keystore as

keytool -export -alias broker -keystore broker.ks -file broker_cert

Comment: Hi Steffen, yes, I saw this somewhere but not quite understand how to do it. I will have a try.. Thanks

Comment: Hi Steffen, thank you for the hint. It's working after setting Subject Alternative Name. Happy to accept your answer.